# Не работает выпадающее меню, при уменьшении разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Только начал разбираться с bootstrap и наткнулся на проблему с не работающим выпадающим списком при уменьшении разрешения экрана. Я так подозреваю ошибка у меня скрывается в не правильном подключении bootstrap, но не могу понять где именно.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Site 0.1v</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Главная</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="callapse" data-target="#">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Вход</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Регистрация</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подключениях у Вас, конечно, фарш полный: зачем-то два раза подключен `jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js`и одновременно `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` + `bootstrap.min.js`.

Но не работает меню не поэтому. У Вас `data-toggle="callapse"` с ошибкой написан - надо `collapse`. И пусто в `data-target="#"` - здесь после октоторпа надо указывать id скрытого меню, в Вашем случае - `data-target="#navbarResponsive"`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Главная</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Вход</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Регистрация</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```